# How to distcp between a MAPR filesystem and a HDInsight Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, mapr, distcp

I'm trying to execute the distcp command below, however it is throwing the exception:

```
hadoop distcp date_load=201901* wasb://dev3-spark@clusterdev.blob.core.windows.net/luiz/producao/performance/performance_report
```

The thrown exception is as follow:

I'm trying to execute the distcp command below, however it is throwing the exception:

hadoop distcp date_load=201901* wasb://dev3-spark@clusterdev.blob.core.windows.net/luiz/producao/performance/performance_report

The thrown exception is as follow:

19/02/06 13:34:53 INFO impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
19/02/06 13:34:53 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
19/02/06 13:34:53 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: azure-file-system metrics system started
19/02/06 13:34:53 ERROR tools.DistCp: Invalid arguments:
org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Container dev3-spark in account clusterdev.blob.core.windows.net not found, and we can't create  it using anoynomous credentials.
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.createAzureStorageSession(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:938)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.initialize(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:438)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.initialize(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1048)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2693)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:98)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2773)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2755)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:411)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:309)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.setTargetPathExists(DistCp.java:216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:116)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.main(DistCp.java:430)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Container dev3-spark in account clusterdev.blob.core.windows.net not found, and we can't create  it using anoynomous credentials.
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.connectUsingAnonymousCredentials(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:730)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.createAzureStorageSession(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:933)
        ... 12 more
Invalid arguments: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Container dev3-spark in account clusterdev.blob.core.windows.net not found, and we can't create  it using anoynomous credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can distcp from your on-premise cluster to your Azure storage account

```
% hadoop distCP hdfs://<yourHostName>:9001/user/<yourUser>/<yourDirectory> wasbs://<yourStorageContainer>@<YourStorageAccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<yourDestinationDirectory>/
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!